# Table taking input as string and parsing and giving output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with below schema which should take string input and give me output:

create table tblA (sName varchar(20), id int);

select * from tblA;

```
insert into tblA (sName, id) values ('Bay', 2), ('Kay', 3), ('May', 4);

select distinct sName
from tblA
where id in ("3,4");
```

O/P:
    Kay

I need:
    Kay
    May

There is an application that sends String and MySQL needs to read that string parse and give an output. The application cannot send integer value.  In the application input is only id. Whatever I enter, it will be converted into String and will be passed to the query. My input will always be comma seperated e.g. (4,5,6). Each 4, 5, 6 is id. But application sends (4,5,6) as a single string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Evidently users enter something - is it a number or a comma-seperated set of numbers? - that your application delivers as a string. You then want to return all the strings in the database that correspond to the number, or one of the comma seperated numbers, entered by the user. Is this correct? I don't know how to do this and I'd rather I went away and tried to work out how to solve your actual problem rather than a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select sName
from tblA
where id in (3, 4)
```

I.e remove the qutation marks from the argument to `in`

**Edit** following OP's comment

```
select sName
from tblA
where id in ('3', '4')
```

i.e. Single quotes and quote each possible value of id.

Comment: The input should be String not integer.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement you provide has id as `int`, not `string`.

Comment: Even if the id column in int not string, application sends input as string not integer. Application sends id as (4,5,6) as String not integer.